# Scale ImageView using Volley Android

Tags: android, image-processing, android-volley

Using Volley library and ViewPager to make an image gallery, I have stumbled upon the problem of scalling images if they are width different width and height. Let's say..landscape mode images and portrait mode images. The portrait images show ok, but the landscape ones are cut at width.  THe view Page height i want to set fixed to 300dp, for instance.

I really don't get this... Bellow is my code:

[image]

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cell, container, false);

        final NetworkImageView imageView = (NetworkImageView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.imageCell);

        RequestQueue queue = VolleySingleton.getInstance(getActivity())
                .getRequestQueue();
        ImageLoader imageLoader = VolleySingleton.getImageLoader();
        imageLoader.get(photoUrl, new ImageListener() {

            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.unnamed); 
            }

            public void onResponse(ImageContainer response, boolean arg1) {
                if (response.getBitmap() != null) {
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(response.getBitmap());
                }
            }
        });
        imageView.setImageUrl(photoUrl, imageLoader);

        return view;
    }
```

Cell.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageCell"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@drawable/unnamed"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

</LinearLayout>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/photoPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:minHeight="100dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"  />

</LinearLayout>
```

I hope somebody has passed this problem before, any hint would be great. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`android:scaleType="fitCenter"` on `NetworkImageView` should do the trick.

Comment: EUREKA!!! there's so many posts that explain huge long answers on how to do this with extending classes, crazy stuff... but this works. THANKS!